# Why does one Testmethod take almost 100ms

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have two test methodes

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void testNotADate()
{
    prepareNewTest();
    excelex.addTimeToDict("testProject", "Not a Date", "Not a Time");
    cleanUp()
}
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void testNotATime()
{
    prepareNewTest();
    excelex.addTimeToDict("testProject", DateTime.Today.ToString(), "Not a Time");
    cleanUp();
}
```

that both test the following VB.net Function:

```
Public Sub addTimeToDict(projectname As String, changeDate As String, time As String)
    If Not Date.TryParse(changeDate, New Date) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("changeDate is not a recoginized Date", "changeDate")
    End If
    If Not Date.TryParse(time, New Date) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("time is not a recoginized time format (enter HH:mm:ss", "time")
    End If
    ///... Actuall Stuff
End Sub
```

Anyone has an idea why the second function, that tests for a valid date takes between 15 and 100ms in the test-Explorer while the one that tests for an invalid time takes less then 1ms?
Also there is an empty teststub that takes an average of 5 ms to execute...
Its not really a bug, but more of a curiosity question

Comment: You shouldn´t bother about some milliseconds, in particular when executing *one single* call to a method (in your case a test-method). Quite often this is just because some initialization going on the first time.

Comment: Well, the time-test has to do the date test anyway, so whatever the first test needs, the second test needs always more. You are testing too much because the `addTimeToDict` does too much.

Comment: Not sure how much, but raising exceptions are expensive operations

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: yes, if the test for a valid time would have taken more time to execution then the test for a valid date I would have understood, but the one that takes longer is actually the testDate method :o